# Character holding an object

Tags: armature, constraints

I'm trying to get a character (robot) to catch a vinyl record. I have both objected linked into a blend file. I tried to use a Child of constraint on the vinyl record and parent it to the thumb bone of the character. It's moving, but it's not following the thumb. In fact it appears like it's going in the opposite direction. below are a couple of screen caps to show my issue[image]

[image]

I'm thinking that some how the bone axes and the object axes are not aligned. So it's not following it properly? But I'm not sure and don't know how to go about fixing that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Has the vinyl record been animated before introducing the child of constraint? Maybe it has some keyframe left that are now interfering. On the other hand, it's hard to tell more without seeing oh the armature is like, modifiers, constraints... I would suggest to upload at least a piece of your file for examination.

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: I'm having trouble separating the blend file to include it here. But I found some info while doing this. I have the robot and the armature grouped. And then I link that group into a separate blend file. Then link the vinyl record into the same file, make proxies (Ctrl+Alt+P), then add the constraint to the record. That doesn't work. When I tried it. the record jumps to the thumb location, but then when I move the armature record doesn't follow. If I append the group instead of link it, then everything works as expected. Am I doing something wrong with proxies?

Comment: My previous comment wasn't entirely correct. I was seeing strange behavior, but as I tried to reproduce again, it seemed to work ok. So I'm suspecting something I did is causing an issue in my original blend file. I also tried linking the robot group in a different blend file, then linking in the action from my animated file, and that also worked. So this could be my work around. I'll just create a blend file and link the robot, action and vinyl record. Here is a link you can download the problem state files from: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By7_pLesGvS0Uk50bjlmTEM3blU

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. when I add the childof constraint I was picking the armature object. But when I used the picker took and pointed it at the armature of the robot, it showed a different object; the proxy. Once I selected that, things worked as I expected.