# How to switch the object's parent from one bone to another? (grab, hold and drop object)

Tags: rigging, parent

I have a character wearing a mask, so at this point the mask is parented to the face bone. The hand will grab it from the face so essentially the parenting will transfer to the hand bone. How do I do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127496/blender-pickup-up-and-dropping-object-setting-visual-keyframes-just-changes-p  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91094/object-child-of-two-parents  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147240/how-can-i-make-my-animated-robot-pick-up-an-object-a-pole-during-an-animation  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87906/robot-arm-move-a-box   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78307/character-holding-an-object

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24581/changing-childof-constraint-influence-to-0-but-keeping-the-position-it-had-as-a

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the *Child Of* constraint. If you don't need to drop the object at the end, here is a quick way to do it:

- Give your object 2 *Child Of* constraints, one with the first bone as *Target*, the second with the second bone. Don't forget to click on the *Set Inverse* button so that the object stays at its place. At frame 0 create a keyframe on the second constraint's *Influence* at 0. Keyframe your bones.

[image]

- At frame 10, move your second bone (hand) from its current position to its position next to the object, and keyframe it. At frame 9 create a keyframe on the first *Influence* > 1, and on the second *Influence* > 0.

[image]

- At frame 10 create a keyframe on the first *Influence* > 0, and on the second *Influence* > 1.

[image]

- At frame 20 move the bone to its new location.

[image]