# How to make characters hand/pass each other objects

Tags: animation, modifiers, constraints

I've been animating a scene and currently have a character holding an object using the child of constraint. Is there anyway I can make the character pass the object to another character (they use the same rig.) I don't see any tutorials online so coming here seemed like a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: you could do it the hard way, meaning keyframing the Visual LocRotScale of the object, but there's an addon called Dynamic Parent that should work for 2.8, explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoXz4IKpoq8   the code is here but I don't know how you import it into Blender: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romanvolodin/dynamic_parent/2.8/dynamic_parent.py

Comment: And I answered in details here, hope this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179852/how-to-switch-the-objects-parent-from-one-bone-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way that you've already created a Child Of constraint for the first character, you can simply create another Child Of constraint for the second character, and point it to the same object as a target. Only, the second character's Child Of constraint should have its influence slider set to zero, and keyframed at zero for whatever length of time that the first character is to have the object in hand. Likewise, the first character should have the Influence slider for its own Child Of constraint set to be fully active, and also keyframed as such, for that same duration. At the time that the hand-off happens, you simply keyframe the influence of both Child Of constraints to have reverse influence from what they both had one single frame beforehand. This works very well. The two characters do not even have to have anything in common regarding their rigs. They certainly don't need to have rigs that are exact copies of one another. They simply each need their own Child Of constraint, and each of them needs to point to the same object. The only thing that changes is the influence.

[image]