# How do I make it so the object will stick to to my character's hand while posing it?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I am trying to make it so when I move my character's arm the drumsticks will move along with it, I connected the object to my character's hand before it was rigged, but the drumsticks were made as a separate object. Any suggestions?
[image: before moving arm]

[image: after moving arm]

Comment: I gave an answer here, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179852/how-to-switch-the-objects-parent-from-one-bone-to-another

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as follows (assuming you want to keep the drumsticks separate from the character).

In edit mode on your character's armature, create two more bones, one in each hand where you'd like the drumsticks to be held. Name them say, handL and handR. Make sure they are parented correctly to the arm bones.

Next enter edit mode for the drumsticks and select all the geometry of one of them, doesn't matter which. Press P and choose "Separate by Selection". Now your drumsticks should be 2 separate objects.

Go back to your armature and select one of the hand bones you made. Press Shift + S and select "Cursor to Selected". Exit the armature and select the drumstick on the same side as the bone you just selected. Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + C and select from the menu "Origin to 3D Cursor". Now the origin (pivot point, the yellow dot) should be where the hand bone is for that side of the body. Do the same process in this paragraph again for the other hand and stick.

Select one of the sticks and enter edit mode. In the side panel choose the tab that has the triangle icon and create a new vertex group, naming it the name of the hand bone the drumstck is on the same side of (i.e. the left stick in this example should now have a vertex group named handL). In edit mode select all the stick's geometry and in the Vertex Group side panel click the Assign button. Exit edit mode and repeat the same with the other stick.

The last thing to do us for each stick go to the Modifiers tab on the side panel and give them each one Armature modifier, choosing the Armature of your character in the box and making sure the Bone Vertex Groups checkbox is marked. If done correctly the sticks should now automatically move with your character's hands. If you want to disable the tracking at any time to control the location of the sticks manually then for each stick simply disable the Armature modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to stick the prop to my character by just constraining and making it a child of the arm bones. Thanks for the help though.